# systemd service: permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, services, systemd

I have a new systemd service that fails to start with a "permission denied" error. 
I bought a Thinkpad L480. Unfortunately, there seems to be an issue with the kernel not detecting the touchpad. This is addressed [here](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/59714?string=59714&project=1&type%5B0%5D=&sev%5B0%5D=&pri%5B0%5D=&due%5B0%5D=&reported%5B0%5D=&cat%5B0%5D=&status%5B0%5D=open&percent%5B0%5D=&opened=&dev=&closed=&duedatefrom=&duedateto=&changedfrom=&changedto=&openedfrom=&openedto=&closedfrom=&closedto=) can be solved by

```
sudo sh -c 'echo -n "elantech" > /sys/bus/serio/devices/serio1/protocol'
```

As I do not want to do this on every single startup, I made a systemd service, which does not work as expected.

My touchpad_enabler.service is

```
[Unit]
Description=FooBar

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/enable_touchpad.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

The script file is simply

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "elantech" > /sys/bus/serio/devices/serio1/protocol
```

But I also tried it with the `sh -c` version. I adjusted the permissions via

```
sudo chmod 744 /usr/local/bin/enable_touchpad.sh
sudo chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/touchpad_enabler.service
```

so both files are owned by root. 
I then enabled it via

```
systemctl enable enable_touchpad.sh
```

When I manually start the service via `systemctl start touchpad_enabler.service`, it works totally fine and the touchpad works as it should. However, on startup , the service fails and is listet as 'failed' in `systemctl list-units`.

The output of `journalctl -b -u touchpad_enabler.service` is:

```
systemd[1]: Starting Solves bug that Thinkpad L480 Touchpad is not correctly detected...
enable_touchpad.sh[516]: sh: /sys/bus/serio/devices/serio1/protocol: permission denied
systemd[1]: touchpad_enabler.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: touchpad_enabler.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start FooBar
```

It looks like the problem is the permission to write to the file itself. But manually starting the service works fine and to my understanding systemd should execute the command as root anyway, right?

From reading `man systemctl.service` I got the idea to prepend '+' to the filepath so that it read

```
ExecStart=+/usr/local/bin/enable_touchpad.sh
```

With no effect.

I do not really understand where this `protocol` file comes from. It looks like it gets created by the kernel on startup? So I also experimented with the `After=` parameter, but systemd should start the services after the kernel is fully loaded, right? The file is also owned by root so I would not expect any problems there.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is SELinux present and in enforcing mode? What is the SELinux context? I believe `enable_touchpad.sh` should have `bin_t` type. Can you verify the script has the type with `ls -Z /usr/local/bin/enable_touchpad.sh`? (Here is an example for one of my scripts that is run by systemd timer and service every hour: `ls -Z fetch-data.sh` returns `unconfined_u:object_r:bin_t:s0 fetch-data.sh`).

Comment: For debugging I would suggest to do an `ls -l /sys/bus/serio/devices/serio1` in your script before trying to write to it.

Comment: if you look at all the services, you can see systemd starts up 'a lot of weird stuff' so probably you need an After= on "something or other"

Answer (score 9):

It seems like you have the service and script files a little confused. The contents of the files seem like they should work though.

Systemd needs a service file. Put this file here

```
/etc/systemd/system/touchpad_enabler.service
```

With the contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=FooBar

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/enable_touchpad.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Then your script here (I changed the name to make the separation between service file and script file clearer. Also `/usr/local/bin` is a better place because it's generally meant for local scripts/programs)

```
/usr/local/bin/enable_touchpad.sh
```

And it will have the contents (unchanged):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "elantech" > /sys/bus/serio/devices/serio1/protocol
```

Make sure the permissions on the script and the service file are correct. They should be owned by root and the script should be executable.

```
sudo chmod 744 /usr/local/bin/enable_touchpad.sh
sudo chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/touchpad_enabler.service
```

Then you enable the systemd service.

```
sudo systemctl enable touchpad_enabler.service
```

This enables the service so it will run at boot. It can also be run manually with:

```
sudo systemctl start touchpad_enabler.service
```

or you can directly run the script, bypassing the systemd service:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/enable_touchpad.sh
```

I can't really speak to the bug or when the protocol file is created, but the service should work.

EDIT:
You can add the `After=` parameter to the `[Unit]` section of the service to make sure it runs after a specific target, like `default.target` or `multi-user.target`. By default, every service has a dependency on `sysinit.target`, so I'm not sure how much that would matter in your case.

If you look here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511139/how-to-make-sysfs-changes-persistent-in-centos-7-systemd, there are other ways to accomplish what you want without a custom service. Maybe you can try a udev rule.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually did everything you mentioned. I just had it wrong in my question (the ExecStart= part) the error message showes, that it did actually find the script, tries to execute it, but lacks permissions. I edited my question where this was yet unclear and changed the filenames according to your suggestion to make it clearer. Manually starting the service works fine. But not loading on startup.

Comment: What did you try with the After option? Does adding `After=default.target` to the `[Unit]` section help?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in my postgresql HA service named: 'Patroni'
So I simply comment out User and Group lines as below:

```
[Service]
Type=simple

#User=postgres
#Group=postgres

ExecStart=/root/.local/bin/patroni /etc/patroni.yml
```

And then reload new configuration:

```
systemctl daemon-reload;
systemctl start <service>
```

Just it!