# postgresql sevice will not start on aws linux 2023

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, postgresql

I am trying to install, configure, and start a `postgresql 12` service on amazon linux 2023. I have installed the service from source and have created a `postgresql.service` file in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/`. I am not able to start the service (I placed the error below) and is there any other configuration that needs to be done? Thank you :)

**contents of postgresql.service**

```
systemd unit configuration
#
# This can be installed as a service on new system with
#   systemctl enable "$PWD/postgresql.service"
#
# Check status with
#   systemctl status postgresql

[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL database server

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/usr/lib/systemd/system
ExecStart="/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service"
TimeoutSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 397 Oct 20 11:52 postgresql.service
```

**error:**

```
× postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
 Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2023-10-20 11:55:36 UTC; 4s ago
Duration: 1ms
Process: 364804 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   

Oct 20 11:55:36 ip- systemd[1]: Started postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server.
Oct 20 11:55:36 ip- systemd[364804]: postgresql.service: Failed to execute /usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service: Exec format error
Oct 20 11:55:36 ip- systemd[364804]: postgresql.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service: Exec format error
Oct 20 11:55:36 ip systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Oct 20 11:55:36 ip- systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: The problem likely is connected to the contents of [`/etc/systemd/system/postgresql.service`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62206481/postgresql12-3-wont-start-on-boot-systemd). [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70742592/systemd-assignment-outside-of-section-ignoring)

Comment: [The line that should likely be removed is `After=remote-network.target` but the permissions error likely is a separate problem](https://superuser.com/questions/1403601/systemd-service-permission-denied). Nobody has permissions to even execute your service by the way.  Try and disable SElinux with `setenforce 0` temporally.

Comment: The updates were made to the service I do not get errors on the command line but the service does not start. Thank you :).

Comment: You made what modifications? Update your question if the situation has changed, the reason the service doesn’t start, is in the logs.

Comment: I removed the `After=remote-network.target`, disabled `SElinux`, and added executable permissions. The service didn't start because of the `ExecStart` which I fixed and the service is running. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the "Permission denied" errors. Use [chmod](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/linux-chmod-chown-change-file-permissions/) to set permissions appropriately, or [start the service as su](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80066/postgresql-service-start-issues).

Answer (score 1):

> ExecStart="/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service"

This makes no sense at all. What do you expect from a service that tries to run itself as an executable?

Let alone that it's not a valid executable anyway.